# How to do int from label(text) WatchKit

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to do int from label (text) for Apple Watch; (Objective-C)
This code working on iPhone:

```
int minNumber = [[minField text] intValue];
```

How to do like that on Apple Watch?

When I tried same code as iPhone app... Error:

```
No visible @interface for 'WKInterfaceLabel' declares the selector 'text'
```

Comment: its not working. Error:  No visible @interface for 'WKInterfaceLabel' declares the selector 'text'

Answer (score 1):

WatchKit objects do not have getters, meaning you cannot read the current value of their properties.

This is described in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH13-SW1):

> Communication between an interface object and the corresponding view on Apple Watch is one way, with information flowing from your WatchKit extension to Apple Watch. In other words, you set values on an interface object but you cannot get the current values of its attributes.

Comment: because of it I'm not able to create random generator from min to max number?

Comment: You'll have to find another way to store and retrieve the values you need. Asking the user to input numbers on their Watch is cumbersome, at best.

Comment: I'm trying to use test(voice) input

Comment: At any rate, my answer explains why you were encountering your original problem.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about input?